# Compile SASS files in a directory via Gulp.js tasks, one of which produces logging output

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, sass, gulp.js

If the `default` task is executed here, the file name to be compiled is passed to the argument of the `CompileSass` function. When the `sass` task is executed, the callback function to be executed at the end is passed by gulp.

The `CompileSass` function logs the file name when it is passed. Also, when anything other than the file name is passed, the log output will not be performed with the `CompileSass` function.

This is easily done by determining the argument with the `typeof` operator.

```
function CompileSass(filePath) {
    const time = process.hrtime();
    const isFilePath = typeof filePath === "string";
    if (isFilePath) { // same if condition
        console.log("compiling now");
    }
    return src(path["sass"])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: "expanded"}))
        .on("end", () => {
            if (isFilePath) { // same if condition
                console.log(`Compiled '${filePath}' now`);
            }
        })
        .pipe(dest("css"))
        .on("end", () => {
            if (isFilePath) { // same if condition
                const TaskTime = prettyTime(process.hrtime(time));
                console.log(`Finished compiled ${TaskTime}`);
            }
        });
}

exports.default = () => {
    watch(dir).on("all", (directory) => {
        CompileSass(directory);
    });
};

exports.sass = series(CompileSass); // in fact, there is other tasks in series function's argument
```

However, this `if` statement is repeated even though the log output conditions are the same. I wanted to consolidate this `if` statement in one place. But I couldn't come up with a good idea for that. I believe that increasing package dependencies leads to management complexity, so I am reluctant to introduce new packages whenever possible.

Is there a good way to make the conditional branch for log output common in the gulp method chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question;

some review remarks before addressing your actual question:

- You never seem to pass `filePath` to `src` but use `path["sass"]` instead
- I always suggest to pipe your `console.log` calls through a `log` function that accepts a severity parameter so that you can customize the level of logging, but that's probably overkill for Gulp

I would add a new function that does nothing, called `doNothing()` and then up front point an `output` function to either `doNothing()` or `console.log()`.

```
function doNothing(){
  //Do nothing
}

function CompileSass(filePath) {
    const time = process.hrtime();
    const out = (filePath === "string") ? console.log : doNothing;
    out("compiling now");

    return src(path["sass"])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: "expanded"}))
        .on("end", () => {
            out(`Compiled '${filePath}' now`);
        })
        .pipe(dest("css"))
        .on("end", () => {
            out(`Finished compiling ${prettyTime(process.hrtime(time))}`);
        });
}

exports.default = () => {
    watch(dir).on("all", (directory) => {
        CompileSass(directory);
    });
};

exports.sass = series(CompileSass); // in fact, there is other tasks in series function's argument
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent feedback Konijn. This time, instead of creating a new function `doNothing`, i decided to create an empty function using `new Function`.

Comment: `You never seem to pass filePath to src but use path [" sass "] instead`> 
Does this mean using `path [" sass "]` instead of `filePath`? If so, it is difficult. / 

This is because `path ["sass"]` is a glob path　(e.g `./sass/*/*.scss`), whereas `filePath` is the actual compiled file name(e.g. `./sass/utility/button.sass`), so it's difficult to replace each other.